# Picasso 2.5.2 image not loading with network policy

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to load an image from url, but adding authorization token. Picasso does not want at all to load it if i add `networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)` is there any problem with it ?

my code :

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + userPrefs.accessToken().get())
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                })
                .build();

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getActivity())
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                .build();
        picasso
                .load(URL)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(ivUserImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "-", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is 
We have three enums to pass to `networkPolicy`

```
NO_CACHE
```

Skips checking the disk cache and forces loading through the network.

```
NO_STORE
```

Skips storing the result into the disk cache.

```
OFFLINE
```

**Forces** the request through the disk cache only, skipping network.

So if we use **OFFLINE**, It will skip the Network.

Also please read this [API for Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to use the offline policy

```
  Picasso.with( getApplicationContext() ).load( link ).networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE ).placeholder( R.drawable.notification ).into( imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with( getApplicationContext() ).load( link ).placeholder( R.drawable.notification ).into( imageView );
                    }
                } );
```